Finding the joint distribution of a continuous and discrete random variable and evaluating independence
We are given $X = \min(S,T)$ and $Y=\max(S,T)$ where $S,T$ are independent, continuous random variables with a probability density function $f$ and CDF $F$. Now we consider the random variable $Z$ which is the indicator of the event $[S<T]$.
We want to determine whether $X,Z$, and $Y,Z$ and the joint distribution of $X,Y$ and $Z$ are independent.
We assume that $\text{supp}(S)=\text{supp}(T)=\mathbb{R}$.
It is straightforward to derive that $F_{X}(x)=2F(x)-(F(x))^2$, $f_{X}(x)=2f(x)(1-F(x))$ and $F_{Y}(y)=(F(y))^2$, $f_{Y}(y)=2f(y)F(y)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.
For the distribution of $Z$, we simply note that $P(Z=1)= P(S<T)$ which can be rewritten as $P(R)$ where $R = \{(s,t): t-s>0\}$. Now, since $S,T$ are independent, we have
$$\begin{align} P(R) &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t) \int_{-\infty}^{t} f(s) \,\mathrm{d}s \, \mathrm{d}t \\&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} F(t)f(t) \,\mathrm{d}t \\&= \frac{1}{2} \end{align}$$
Therefore we have, $P(Z=1)=P(Z=0)=1/2$ and the CDF of $Z$ is
$$ F_{Z}(z) =\begin{cases} 0 & ; z<0, \\
                         1/2 & ; 0 \le z <1 \\
                           1 & ;1 \le z 
    \end{cases} $$
To determine the independence of $X,Z$, we try to find their joint CDF and see whether it factors into their marginals.
This is where my trouble begins, because I am not sure whether I am evaluating the joint CDF correctly, because it happens to be one of a continuous random variable with a discrete random variable. Here is how my attempt went:
Clearly, $F_{X,Z}(x,z)=0$ for $z<0$.
For $z \in [0,1)$, we have
$$F_{X,Z}(x,z)=F_{X|Z}(x|z)F_{Z}(z)=P(X\le x|Z\le z)P(Z\le z)$$.
Since $ z \in [0,1)$, we have $F_Z(z)=1/2$ and $P(X\le x|Z\le z)= P(T\le x)=F(x)$ since $z \in [0,1)$ implies that $X=T$ since $X=\min(S,T)$ and $Z$ is the indicator of the event $[S<T]$. So finally we have $F_{X,Z}(x,z)=\frac{1}{2} F(x)$ for $ z \in [0,1)$ but for the same range of $z$ that is not equal to $F_{X}(x) F_Z(z)=\frac{1}{2}(2F(x)-(F(x))^2)$. This should imply that they are not independent, but the answer given to us is that they are infact independent. I am not too sure my calculations regarding the joint CDF have been correct, so any help regarding the final result is very much appreciated.
To give a little context, this is from an assignment in an introductory course in probability theory.

Be careful about removing the condition from conditional probabilities. You have for $z \in [0,1)$ that
$$P(X\leq x : | : Z\leq z) = P(T \leq x : | : Z \leq z)$$
which is not necessarily the same as $P(T \leq x)$.

To show the independence of
$$\tag1
X=\min(S,T)\,,\quad Z=1_{\{S<T\}}
$$
when $S,T$ are i.i.d we have to show that, for all $x,y,z\in \mathbb R$
$$\tag2
\mathbb P\Big\{X\le x,Z\le z\Big\}=\mathbb P\big\{X\le x\big\}\mathbb P\big\{Z\le z\big\}
$$
holds. As you showed, $\mathbb P\big\{S<T\big\}=\mathbb P\big\{S\ge T\big\}=1/2$ and
$$\tag3
\mathbb P\big\{Z\le z\big\}=
\cases{
0\,,& if $z<0\,,$\\[2mm]
\frac 12\,,& if $0\le z<1\,,$\\[2mm] 1\,,& $z\ge 1\,.$}
$$
So let's consider the probability on the LHS of (2) in the following cases

Case $z<0\,.$ Since $Z$ takes values in $\{0,1\}$ the set of which we take this probability is empty and has probability zero. That happens to be the value of  the RHS of (2). Done.

Case $z\ge 1\,.$ Obviously $\{Z\le z\}=\Omega$ and the expression $Z\le z$ can be dropped from both sides of (2). Done.

Case $0\le z<1\,.$  In this case $\{Z\le z\}=\{Z=0\}=\{S\ge T\}=\{X=T\}\,.$ Therefore, the LHS of (2) is
\begin{align}\tag4
\mathbb P\big\{T\le x;T\le S\big\}=F(x)-\frac{F(x)^2}2\,.
\end{align}
This equality is not hard to show by
integrating the joint PDF of $S$ and $T\,.$ Similarly, the first probability on the RHS of (2) is
$$\tag6
\mathbb P\big\{X\le x\big\}=\mathbb P\big\{T\le x;T\le S\big\}\cup
\mathbb P\big\{S\le x;S<T\big\}
=2F(x)-F(x)^2
$$
where  we use (4) and the symmetry in $S$ and $T$ to see that both probabilities in the middle of (6)
are equal.
Together with (3) this proves (2).

Proof of (4).



\begin{align}&\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\min(x,s)}f(t)f(s)\,dt\,ds=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(s)F(\min(x,s))\,ds\\[2mm]&=\int_{-\infty}^xf(s)F(s)\,ds+\int_x^{+\infty}f(s)F(x)\,ds\\[2mm]&=\frac{F(x)^2}{2}+F(x)(1-F(x))=F(x)-\frac{F(x)^2}{2}\,.\tag6\end{align}


The quickest way to show the independence of
$$\tag7
Y=\max(S,T)\,,\quad Z=1_{\{S<T\}}
$$
is to write them as
$$
Y=-\min(-S,-T)\,,\quad Z=1_{\{-T<-S\}}
$$
and use the result about $X$ and $Z\,.$

Another remark is that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent (exercise).
Therefore $X,Y,Z$ are not independent.



Thank you very much for such a nice answer. Overnight thinking about the problem I did realise that my CDF evaluation has been incorrect and I arrived at the correct answer via symmetry considerations. That is $P( (T \le x) \cap (T < S)) = P( (S \le x) \cap (S < T))$, therefore we can say our required probability is equal to $\frac{1}{2} \left( P( (T \le x) \cap (T < S)) + P( (S \le x) \cap (S < T)) \right) = \frac{1}{2} P(\min(S,T) \le x) = \frac{1}{2} F_X(x) = F_X(x)F_Z(z)$

I should clarify in the question that I meant to ask of the independence of the joint distribution of $X,Y$ with that of $Z$.

@Hunter I don't know what independence of the joint distribution of $X,Y$ with that of $Z$ means. If you want to know whether $X,Y,Z$ are independent then set up the equation you have to show (it resembles my (2)) and perform similar steps. In fact, that is what I did initially but did not post it. From doing it ourselves we learn the most.  Clean up your old post and let me know where you get stuck. Last hint: it is enough to show that $X,Y$ are not independent.

My interpretation of the question, as stated in my assignment, was that whether $F_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)=F_{X,Y}(x,y) F_Z(z)$ is true? They stated that as asking if $(X,Y)$ and $Z$ are independent. This question has been picked, as I have come to find, from Jim Pitman's Probability. I believe this assertion to be true, since $F_{X,Y, Z}(x,y,z)$ does factor into $F_{X,Y}(x,y) F_{Z}(z)$.

@Hunter my quick simulation shows that it does factor. I am too lazy to prove it. Can you?

Yes, the symmetry argument works again. We only need to consider $z \in [0,1)$. For this interval we have $ F_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)=P(X \le x, Y \le y, T<S)= P(T \le x, S \le y, T<S)$ but by symmetry this is equal to $P(S \le x, T \le y, S <T)$ so we have that $F_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{2}(P(S \le x, T \le y, S <T)+P(T \le x, S \le y, T<S) )= \frac{1}{2} P(\min(S,T) \le x, \max(S,T) \le y)= \frac{1}{2} F_{X,Y}(x,y)$.
